# Python command from powershell works or fails depending on how/where powershell is started

Tags: python, windows, powershell, environment-variables

I just installed python and checked the box to setup environment variables. I was trying to see the different ways i could start python as per my convenience (start menu, command prompt, python shell, etc.) and that's when I found something weird happening, which i can't understand why?

So when I start a powershell from start menu and type the command `python`, python starts up. And when i start a powershell in desktop location (shift + right click -> open power shell) the `python` command is still accessible(shown in image below). 
[image: python accessible in the powershell started in desktop location]
However when I start a powershell in any other location (say e:/python/playground) by navigating to it using windows explorer and then running the powershell from shift + right_click menu, the `python` command isn't accessible.
[image: python inaccessible in powershell started in a specific location]
But if i start a powershell from start menu and then `cd` to the same location, then the `python` command becomes accessible.
[image: python accessible when powershell started from startmenu and navigated to particular location]
Why do I see different behaviour for `python` for different ways of starting a powershell? It makes me think if there is a difference in environment setup for the shell?

Comment: I'd say when you output `$env:path` you won't see the python executable.

Comment: You're right! But why so? The path is set in the system environment variables.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the ouput of `gcm python` on every pathes you posted. Also please remove the screenshot and replace them by code snippetes. Makes i easier to read. Thanks.

Comment: In which environment variable? It has to be set in `%PATH%`, which it isn't according to your confirmation on my comment

Comment: If you configured Explorer's options to "launch folder windows in a separate process", then this separate explorer.exe instance does not update its environment in response to the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message that Python's installer broadcasts. So if you run powershell.exe from the context menu in this folder window, its environment will not have the updated `PATH` value. You have to terminate the explorer.exe process for that window (not the main explorer.exe process) and open a new file explorer window.

Comment: @Clijsters `gcm` is showing python path! And after system reboot, `python` is visible everywhere.

Comment: @eryksun that option is unchecked. However after a restart `python` is accessible everywhere. Could there be  a similar explanation for that?

Comment: I used Process Explorer to inspect the environment of all instances of explorer.exe after manually updating the environment. Only the instance that hosts the desktop shell updated its environment. Since we know that the environment-variable editor (and also Python's installer) broadcasts `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` to all top-level windows, it seems explorer.exe instances that only host folder windows intentionally ignore this message. I assume this is due to a hard-coded assumption that folder windows are hosted in the same process as the desktop shell.

Comment: Obviously after rebooting, or even after logging off and back on, all instances of Explorer will have the updated environment. See if you can reproduce the issue manually. Open a folder window. Update the environment. Then launch PowerShell from the folder's context menu. If it doesn't have the updated environment, use Process Explorer to check whether its parent explorer.exe instance updated its environment.

Comment: Wait... you didn't reboot after installing? Windows isn't mac ;)

Comment: @Clijsters, in this case in general there's no need to reboot.

Comment: This is partly incorrect. Environment variable changes are broadcasted but this does not "reload" those automatically in running processes. This could lead into strange behaviour. Thats why mot of installation processes on windows require reboots. Sure, you could manually restart services and processes, but why would you if you can just reboot your computer?

Comment: @Clijsters, in *this case* in general there is no need to reboot. We're talking about installing Python and modifying `PATH` to add its installation and scripts directories  and `PATHEXT` to add .PY as an executable extension. The process the OP is interested in for this case is simply explorer.exe, the parent of powershell.exe. It's only in the case of a standalone file explorer process that I've observed any problem at all. This is a bug in Explorer, which fails to modify the behavior of its window procedure when running in a separate process.